# How to determine Java Servlet / Spring session timeout and good practise

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies, spring-security

I noticed that the jsessionId will get sent across to the server so in the filter I could actually get the expired session id from the cookies.

Is it ok to put a filter logic like the following?

```
Cookie jsessionCookie = getSessionIdCookies(request);
Session session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null || !(jsessionCookie.getValue().equals(session.getId())) {
    //this should be a timeout handling
    ....
} else {
    // normal moving forward
}
```

Since the `session == null` could also because of a new request (which can be filtered out by setting particular filter rules), can I more rely on `!(jsessionCookie.getValue().equals(session.getId())`?

Or even change the `request.getSession(false)` to  `request.getSession()` and just always compare the cookie with the session id?

Is there a better management practice for session timeout management?

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) on the ServletContext to get notified when a session is invalidated.